# React native App is getting crashed. Logcat logs are as described below-

Tags: android, reactjs, crash, native, mobile-application

```
2020-11-13 16:35:41.850 27509-27525/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: create_react_context
    Process: com.sehat, PID: 27509
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load script. Make sure you're either running a Metro server (run 'react-native start') or that your bundle 'app.bundle' is packaged correctly for release.
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.jniLoadScriptFromAssets(Native Method)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.loadScriptFromAssets(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:235)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JSBundleLoader$1.loadScript(JSBundleLoader.java:29)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.runJSBundle(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:259)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.createReactContext(ReactInstanceManager.java:1243)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.access$1000(ReactInstanceManager.java:132)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager$5.run(ReactInstanceManager.java:996)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Comment: Please add more details, it's not clear what you wanted to achieve and how you got this error.

Comment: As the crash report says do you try running `react-native start` on a separate terminal? after building your project with `react-native run-android`

Comment: Hi I have installed the React native App on the device and after installation I get these logs with an app crash on opening the app.